# How to replace something with n duplicates of itself with regex?

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3, backreference

I am using Sublime Text.

I want to replace `Hi` with 30 of itself, so I captured `(Hi)` in the find field, and entered `$1{30}` in the replace field. This didn't work. What is the proper syntax to do this?

I can't find the answer through Google, even though it seems very basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no backreference multiplication operators in replacement patterns, nor can you use limiting quantifiers (that are *regex pattern* constructs, not *replacement pattern* constructs) like you did to achieve that result.

The only proper "plain regex" way is to repeat `$1` thirty times.

In programming languages though, there are occastions when you can pass the match object to a callback function, where you can already use string manipulation provided by the programming language, [e.g. in Python](https://ideone.com/qG6Up5):

```py
import re
text = "Hi, Friend!"
print( re.sub(r'Hi', lambda z: z.group() * 30, text) )
# => HiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHiHi, Friend!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know of any other tools to achieve this? I have a list with 30 items and I want to duplicate each of them 30 times, to get a list with 900 items.

Comment: @user17038038 Well, as I say, you need to repeat the backreference as many times in the replacement pattern, as you need. Else, consider processing the content with some proper full-fledge programming language.

Comment: @user17038038 Also, when you ask about "other" tools, it is important to mention the OS you are working in. Also, it is not clear what "items" you mean. If you need some more help, please add the real life explanation/examples into the question.

Comment: To echo what Wiktor said, this is much more easily accomplished using either a full programming language like Python, Ruby, JavaScript, etc., or using Unix/Linux command-line tools and/or shell scripting. Regex is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks, I'll try to add those details when I have a new question. In this case each item a string of approximately 15 characters, but I already resolved the issue.

Comment: @user17038038  Glad you did, could you please share how exactly you solved the problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used excel. I entered the list of 30 items into a column. Next, I selected the column and dragged the bottom corner to the right to create 30 columns. So now I have 30 rows with each row having 30 duplicates. Then I just copy and pasted it into sublime text and replaced `\t` with `\n`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure, I did already upvote the answer because it was helpful even though I ended up using a different approach. Thanks again

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I accepted your answer because after finding out this couldn't be done with regex, my problem would have required creating a new question to be properly addressed. Thus, based on the question itself, I think you had a good answer.